# error in printing a N-Dimensional Numpy Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

Im having problems with printing an numpy 6-Dimentional Matrix.
    import numpy as np
    QMatrix = np.zeros((((((5,6,10,12,10,8))))))

I used this and after populating the matrix fully I tried to print the matrix using

```
print (QMatrix)
```

then It comes up as bunch of zeros. but when I specifically search for a value in the Matrix it gives me the correct value.

```
print (QMatrix[1][2][4][2][5][7])
>>> 12.45
```

do I have to convert the matrix in some sort before printing the matrix
Here is the full code that I used

```
class Q_Matrix_Base(object):
 def __init__(self, LeadVehSpd,LeadVehiPos,EstDiscTime,FolVehSpeed,FolVehPos,RGT):
        self.LeadVehSpd = LeadVehSpd
        self.LeadVehiPos = LeadVehiPos
        self.EstDiscTime = EstDiscTime
        self.FolVehPos = FolVehPos
        self.FolVehSpeed = FolVehSpeed
        self.RGT = RGT

        # initialize matrix and fill with zeroes
        self.QMatrix =  np.zeros((((((LeadVehSpd,LeadVehiPos,EstDiscTime,FolVehSpeed,FolVehPos,RGT))))))
        #self.QMatrix.fill(0)

 def setitem (self ,LeadVehSpd,LeadVehiPos,EstDiscTime,FolVehSpeed,FolVehPos,RGT,Reward): #assign the values for the specific place


      self.QMatrix[LeadVehSpd,LeadVehiPos,EstDiscTime,FolVehSpeed,FolVehPos,RGT] = Reward

 def getitem (self,LeadVehSpd,LeadVehiPos,EstDiscTime,FolVehSpeed,FolVehPos,RGT): #get the value from a row and a column
    return self.QMatrix[LeadVehSpd][LeadVehiPos][EstDiscTime][FolVehSpeed][FolVehPos][RGT]

 def printMaa (self,lk):
    np.save('C:\\example\\MatrixsecondStage2.npy', self.QMatrix)
    return self.QMatrix

 def getposspeed (self,LeadVehSpd,LeadVehiPos,EstDiscTime,FolVehPos,RGT): #to select a specific row(i) in a matrix
    return self.QMatrix[LeadVehSpd,LeadVehiPos,EstDiscTime,:,FolVehPos,RGT]
```

Comment: All those parentheses in your call will be ignored: without commas, they mean "evaluate".
You seem to be making an array of only zeros, so why is 12.45 the "right value"?
Finally, you should usually use multiple indices in a single selection rather than multiple selections: `QMatrix[1,2,4,2,5,7]`.

Comment: WIth your code, I get 0.0 as expected. Is your numpy installation up to date? Another guess is that you may be in a situation of insufficient memory.

Comment: @mdurant this numpy matrix is filled out by  simulator. so for this examples sake lets say    QMatrix[1][2][4][2][5][7] = 12.45]

Comment: @mdurant and I have tried with commans as well and that does not work as well.

Comment: @Bookend. Values will be filled out by a simulator. that code bit is not in here. my numpy version is up to date as well. if it is a case of insufficient memory what should I do?

Comment: If you were running out of memory, you would get an error saying so. Here's a guess: when you print, numpy only shows you some sample data - are you sure your data is not actually supposed to be zero in the piece you see?

Comment: @mdurant Thank you. but when I run getposspeed. I am getting all the values in that specific row. that means it is saving the values in the matrix. but When I tried PrintMaa it gives me zeros